# DVD or USB to install Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, usb, dvd

My ASUS notebook K53E is currently running under Windows 7. I would like to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows and be able to choose between these two systems each time I start the computer.

I have downloaded Ubuntu and burned a DVD. When restarting my computer (with this DVD in the drive) the DVD is ignored, i.e. Windows is run as usual. When I press delete while rebooting (still with this DVD in the drive) a BIOS set up menu is shown with plenty of things to enable/unable, add, etc. But I don't really know what to do/choose.

When I exit this menu, again,  the DVD is ignored, i.e. Windows is run as usual.
Bascially: I'm stuck.

Question: Is it worth while trying to install Ubuntu from a USB stick rather from a DVD? I.e. is Ubuntu easier to install from a USB than from a DVD? Or am I likely to run into the same kind of problems?

Comment:

Thanks Alina and DVJ for your answers. So I guess the answer to my main question is: no, installation form a USB stick is not really easier than from DVD.

Following your advice about the boot priorities, I have now achieved a little improvement: I now get to GNU GRUB where I can choose to 'install Ubuntu'. Unfortunately, after that the screen goes completely grey and nothing happens.

Comment: ubuntu can be booted up with both usb or dvd.trying to install ubuntu from usb is an easy way.

Answer (score 1):

A few things. On the splash screen for your bios (very first screen) there may be an option to press a key to enter the boot menu. If there is, ensure to press the respective key to enter your boot menu.

If that does not exist you may need to go into the Bios itself (that spot you mentioned that has a bunch of enable/disable options) Somewhere in there there will be a screen that gives you the option of moving drives into order of preferance that it boots from. Ensure CD/DVD drive is a head of your harddrive. Save your settings and restart and it should then give you an option to boot from the DVD.

As for the USB, without having a boot menu that you can access from that first splash screen - it may actually be harder to boot from the USB device as not all BIOS support have the option in the device boot list for USB drives.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to install a new OS from whether a DVD or a USB stick, you need to change the boot order. In the BIOS, go to **Boot** – there should be a tab or major portion with this title.

Under boot you may see the boot order or a submenu to change boot priority. This may differ on different computers. In some computers you can press Enter on the **first boot** option to choose the preferred one (DVD or USB/external). In some others you need to press F5/F6 to arrange to move the preferred one upwards. Look at the bottom of screen where you can see a manual for keys.

I’ve seen some computers that you need to set USB boot under the harddisk devices.

**Note:** in the case you’re installing via a USB stick, insert the media before entering BIOS.

DVD or USB? No difference really (on installation). But the USB can save your changes and settings if you use it in live mode and can be faster than DVD. Plus that you can re-use it afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what to do. Completely shut down your computer. Turn it back on. While it is booting, look in the lower right and left corner. Go into the BIOS by pressing F12, F11, F10, F9, F8, F7, F6, F5, F4, F3, F2, or F1. They are all at the top of the keyboard. G into the boot settings and set the CD drive to the first priority. Hit F10. Start up as usual. You're done.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the ways of installing Ubuntu are same , lyk either you burn DVD or create bootable USB Stick, you have to change BIOS Boot Priority for booting,  and then same simple steps for both . Installing from USB is little more simple because it takes little lesser time to install ..

Answer (score 0):

you need to read this: [HowToInstallUbuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation) and if you create completely new System, you can also read this: [HowToPartition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation)

Answer (score -1):

there is  another way.  download onto your  windows  hdd and use the  installation setup file from within windows.

Comment: Do you mean [wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows)? That's no longer supported.

Comment: not if you use a current disk, you would need to use an older one.  of course the best way is to install onto USB then live installtion